# Limit the result when using following:: in XSL select

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have a complex XML input, which I need to transform into a flat structure, that denormelize the tree in the XML document by repeating the related nodes.

Source XML lookes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="forom%20sample.xsl"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>John Madsen</Name>
        <Accounts>
            <Account>
                <ID>111</ID>
                <Name>AAA</Name>
                <Value>11234</Value>                
            </Account>
            <Account>
                <ID>222</ID>
                <Name>BBB</Name>
                <Value>64</Value>
            </Account>
        </Accounts>
        <Profile>
            <Gender>M</Gender>
            <Age>32</Age>
        </Profile>
    </Customer>

    <Customer>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>Dona M. Graduate</Name>
        <Accounts>
            <Account>
                <ID>333</ID>
                <Name>CCC</Name>
                <Value>5215</Value>                
            </Account>
            <Account>
                <ID>555</ID>
                <Name>FFF</Name>
                <Value>6325</Value>
            </Account>
        </Accounts>
        <Profile>
            <Gender>F</Gender>
            <Age>36</Age>
        </Profile>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Desired flat structure should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Accounts>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>John Madsen</CustomerName>
     <ID>111</ID>
     <Name>AAA</Name>
     <Value>11234</Value>
     <Gender>M</Gender>
     <Age>32</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>John Madsen</CustomerName>
     <ID>222</ID>
     <Name>BBB</Name>
     <Value>64</Value>
     <Gender>M</Gender>
     <Age>32</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>Dona M. Graduate</CustomerName>
     <ID>333</ID>
     <Name>CCC</Name>
     <Value>5215</Value>
     <Gender>F</Gender>
     <Age>36</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>Dona M. Graduate</CustomerName>
     <ID>555</ID>
     <Name>FFF</Name>
     <Value>6325</Value>
     <Gender>F</Gender>
     <Age>36</Age>
  </Account>
```

I am using the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Accounts>
        <xsl:for-each select="Customers/Customer/Accounts/Account">
            <Account>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Customer/*[not(*)]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*" />

                <xsl:copy-of select="following::Profile/*"/>
            </Account>                
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Accounts>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Customer/*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('Customer', name())}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

However, the result I get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Accounts>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>John Madsen</CustomerName>
     <ID>111</ID>
     <Name>AAA</Name>
     <Value>11234</Value>
     <Gender>M</Gender>
     <Age>32</Age>
     <Gender>F</Gender>
     <Age>36</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>John Madsen</CustomerName>
     <ID>222</ID>
     <Name>BBB</Name>
     <Value>64</Value>
     <Gender>M</Gender>
     <Age>32</Age>
     <Gender>F</Gender>
     <Age>36</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>Dona M. Graduate</CustomerName>
     <ID>333</ID>
     <Name>CCC</Name>
     <Value>5215</Value>
     <Gender>F</Gender>
     <Age>36</Age>
  </Account>
  <Account>
     <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
     <CustomerName>Dona M. Graduate</CustomerName>
     <ID>555</ID>
     <Name>FFF</Name>
     <Value>6325</Value>
     <Gender>F</Gender>
     <Age>36</Age>
  </Account>
```

Note that the first node have two Gender and two Age nodes, what happens is that the keyword following:: is not limiting it self to following nodes within the current Customer node, it rather takes all the follwing nodes in the entire document.

So my question is, how can I limit the following:: keyword? Or is there another way to copy the profile child nodes into each account node?

Thanks
Rafi Asraf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling::Profile` on the parent `Accounts` element instead of the overly broad -for this particular case- selector `following::Profile` :

```
<xsl:copy-of select="../following-sibling::Profile/*"/>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform.net demo`](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6D)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks! I knew that there is the following-sibling keyword, however I did not thought that the select acceptes the ../ syntax.

Comment: @sirpadk that's just abbreviated version of`parent::*` or `parent::Accounts` for this particular case